# Disable Previous Button in IzPack

Tags: installation, izpack, griffon

I have an installer using IzPack that installs a Groovy/Griffon project, and it uses the installer plugin for griffon that does so. I would like to restrict one panel's previous button through the installer.xml. One of our testers has determined that (with a very vanilla installer from Griffon's plugin) clicking the previous button after the actual unpacking and installation causes the shortcut screen to be blank, causing some issues. Is this possible, or will I have to write some panel Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the previous button. look at [here](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491687/Custom+Panels)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I've just found out the new location of the link @frewper pointed out: https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491687/Custom+Panels. See the _Controlling Flow_ section

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to make a custom panel for this purpose.